# Triangle number: for nested loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code snippet

```
n = int(input())
for a in range(0, n+1):
    for j in range(1, a+1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

Input:

```
5
```

Output:

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

I had a problem while practicing coding. When I came across this piece of code, I didn't know how it worked. Please help me answer everyone!

Thanks everyone! :))

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Which part don't you understand?

Comment: It first inputs an integer and saves it in `n`.  It then iterates `a` from `0` through `n`.  Then, for each value of `a`, it iterates `j` from `1` through `a`.  For each iteration of `j`, it prints `j`, followed by a space (but no newline).  After the `j` loop exits, it prints a newline charcter, ending the in-progress line, and proceeds to the next value of `a`.  That's the entire program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that the part you don't understand is this line:

```py
print(j, end=' ')
```

What it does is print the number `j`, and then uses ' ' (i.e. space) as the end character.
Usually with the `print` function, the default end character is `\n` (on mac/linux) or `\r\n` on Windows which is a line feed, and the next `print` prints on a new line.

Here the number is printed, and then a space is printed, without a line feed. The next number is then printed on the same line after the space because we didn't print a line feed.
At the end of each first loop, there is a `print()`, which effectively prints nothing but a uses the default end character, and therefore prints a new line, and the next loop over the numbers starts at that new line.

for the lines:

```py
for a in range(0, n+1): 
   for j in range(1, a+1):
```

the first line does a for loop over the range 0 to n (with a step size of 1). the `range is inclusive on the left and exclusive on the right, that is if n = 3, it goes over 0, 1, 2, 3

Second loop is the same but over 1 to a + 1, a being the value from the first loop, so it increases at each run of the loop.

The second loop runs inside the first one, so when a = 0, it runs 1 to 1 (1 time) and print `1`, then a = 2, it runs for j = 1 and j = 2, and prints `1 2`, when a = 2, second loop runs for j = 1, j= 2, j = 3, and print `1 2 3` and so on.
The first loop runs n times, so if n = 5 it prints 5 lines.

Comment: I don't understand this line:
```
for a in range(0, n+1):
    for j in range(1, a+1):
```
Thanks everyone!